# How do you read the vertex buffer in the fragment shader?

Tags: rendering, vulkan, vertex

I am trying to read my vertex data in the fragment shader to try some rendering experiments. It is possible to do this, and if so, what is the best way?

My guess is that buffer views are meant to be used, but I didnt find anything about them online and am unsure how exactly to use them.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the implementation doesn't forbid using the same buffer as a vertex buffer and an SSBO (or buffer view, if you want to do it that way), you can do it. You simply bind the buffer for use as both things.